# lightning-record-edit-form not saving

Tags: lightning-web-components

This LWC was added to the C_Case__c record page. The Update button doesn't work. The alert of the recordId shows the id of the C_Case__c. I'm not sure what I'm missing. The update should happen without having to code anything, right?

html:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={showUpdate}>
        <lightning-card title="Update Notes" icon-name="custom:custom18">
            <lightning-record-edit-form
                    record-id={recordId}
                    object-api-name="C_Case__c"
                    onsubmit={updateNotes}
                    onsuccess={handleSuccess}
                    onerror={handleError}>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Notes__c"></lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-button label="Update" type="submit" name="Save" variant="brand" icon-name="utility:save"></lightning-button>&nbsp;
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </lightning-card>
    </template>
</template>
```

js:

```
export default class LitNotes extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;  //The parent record Id.
    @track showUpdate = true;

    updateNotes(event) {
        console.log(this.recordId);
        alert(this.recordId);
    }

    handleSuccess() {
        console.log(this.litId);
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Notes updated',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
    }
    handleError(event) {
        let errorMessage = event.detail.detail;
        console.log("response",errorMessage);
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error',
                message: errorMessage,
                variant: 'error'
            })
        );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: just use  handleSuccess(event) {
       alert(event.detail.id);
    }  and no need to write onsubmit as of now

Comment: Did you get any errors in the `handleError` function? there might be some data validation errors.

Comment: I don't know what happened to be honest. . . I made Sahil's change and it worked. I undid the change and it still works.